# getppid() not returning parent's pid

Tags: c++, linux, pid, fork

I have been trying to learn about fork and processes. I just encountered a small problem with this piece of code and was trying to understand why?.
I was trying to duplicate a process by a system call `Fork` and with the value of `pid` being positive, it hit the parent and its `getpid()` was returned. And simultaneously it hit the child and its `getpid()` was returned. But the problem was, when I called up the `getppid()` here, it was expected to show its parent's process identifier, which happened to be **3370**.
But upon compilation and execution of this file, it showed the value of `getppid()` as **1517** (not parent's id).

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Oracle VM VirtualBox (32-bit O.S.). The code of this `forking.cpp` file is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid1;
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == -1)
    {
        cout << "No child process formed: " << getpid() <<endl;
    }
    else if(pid1 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Child has been formed: " << getpid()<< " and its parent's id: " << getppid() << endl;
    }
    else if(pid1 > 0)
    {   
        cout << "Parent process has been called: " << getpid() << endl;

    }

    cout << "END of Stuffs" << endl;
    return 0;
    exit(0);
}
```

For compilation, I was using the command `g++ forking.cpp` on terminal and for executing, `./a.out`.
Then it showed this:

```
Parent process has been called: 3370
END of Stuffs
Child has been formed: 3371 and its parent's id: 1517
END of Stuffs

shashish-vm@shashishvm-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

I know that trivially, if a parent dies before its child, the child is automatically adopted by the original "init" process, with `PID` 1. But here it is definitely not this case.

Comment: Can't reproduce, both ppids are the same as expected here when running your code.

Comment: You have to wait for the child in the parent. [Example](http://ideone.com/YnVGH0).

Comment: If the parent keels over before the child reaches its `getppid()` the process id will be replaced in the running table. `wait(NULL)` inside your *parent* if-block after its output as n.m suggested should get you there (barring running in a debugger that reparents the world, which isn't entirely uncommon).

Comment: Yes, you are right, i tried that and it worked out. Still, I worry about why the parent process terminates before the child is executed?.

Comment: I mean, in this case specifically I am neither `sleep`-ing the child process nor making it halt. So, ideally both the processes should run parallely and end up showing the results simultaneously.

Comment: Your processes are running so quickly that you can't know which one is exiting first. So you need to add a `sleep` or a `wait` etc... Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Ok. But in such cases where the parent process terminates beforehand, the child process is automatically adopted by the `init` process. So, the PID after reparenting should give 1 as the value of `getppid()`and not the above mentioned value, right?

Comment: These days with `systemd` running rampant we don't even know if `pid 1` is special any more.

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurs when the parent process terminates before the execution of `getppid()`. Use `wait(NULL)` at the end the parent to solve the problem.