# Fork and kill in C++ crashes ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, crash, fork, kill

i have problem with small piece of my code.

```
void setTimeout(int time)
{
    if (fork() == 0) {
        pid_t id = getppid();
        sleep(time);
        if(kill(id, 0) == ESRCH)
            return;
        cerr << "Time out!" << endl;
        kill(id, TIMEOUT);
        return;
    }
}
```

When the parent process is running and I don't need to kill him, nothing happens and it close as it should, but if parent process ends before timeout, ubuntu crashes.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked some [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "ubuntu crashes"?

Comment: @Clearer It drops to login screen

Comment: @Drop Yep, nothing is there about crashes

Comment: That means something else is crashing but it's not "Ubuntu". It's whatever controls your session; gnome-session/shell, graphics server or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the parent process terminates, getppid will return the process id of the shell that launched it.  So you are killing the shell, which is why you drop to the login screen.

See also:

[getppid() not returning parent's pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385235/getppid-not-returning-parents-pid)